# Type with dynamically imported type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm junior frontend developer

Currently, working on multilingual project with next.js + typescript

I'm trying to import type from each locale dynamically (kr, en)

Is it possible to type with dynamically imported type in TypeScript..?

So here's what I've tried

```js
// @project/kr/foo
export enum foo {
 KIMCHI = 'kimchi',
 JOKBAL = 'jokbal'
}

// @project/en/foo
export enum foo {
 CHEESE = 'cheese',
 PIZZA = 'pizza'
}

// locale common component 
const { foo } = require(`@project/${process.env.LOCALE}/foo`)

interface bar {
 foo: typeof foo
}
```

With this, I get 'any' type for foo

If you know and tell me possible way to enable this,
You'll be my savior..

Thank you :)

Comment: interface bar extends foo {
yourextratypehere: string
} OR type bar = foo & {yourextratypehere: string}

Answer (score 0):

To import in the typescript (.ts) file:

```
import { foo } from "@project/en/foo";
```